# How can I use git log to show all prior commits that moved or deleted an occurrence of a particular search string or regex?

Tags: git

How can I use git log to show all prior commits that moved or deleted an occurrence of a particular search string or regex?

For example if I do:

```
git log -S mystring
```

Right now, it will just show the list of commits that changed the number of occurrences of the search string, "mystring." However it won't show which files it was changed in, or the diffs, etc.

I want to only see those commits that *decreased* the number of occurrences, along with a diff showing which files the deletion of that symbol occurred in (but no other diffs).

Comment: Have you looked at building something up based on `-G<regex>`?  I know it isn't the full solution, but I think it will at least find all potential candidates for you.  I'm just curious, and want to make sure you didn't miss the option (guessing you didn't).

Comment: I did try -G<regex> and the output seems identical to git log -S. There doesn't seem to be a way to only show deletions, but I found if I do `git log -p -G handleSaveButtonPressed --pickaxe-all` then it shows all the diffs of each commit, not just of the changed file but everything. But then I can search through the output. This is not ideal but it's a workaround unless someone has a better solution.

Comment: At least it awesomely says "pickaxe" in it.

Comment: Add `-p` to your `-S` to get patches displayed. As you note in comments, -G and -S mostly do the same thing: the key difference is that -G (grep) takes a regex *and* selects the commit if there is any match at all, but -S takes a string (by default) and selects the commit if and only if the *number of matches* changes (in the pre- and post- diff images). Note that `git log -p` doesn't show merges very well unless you also add `-m`, so if you want to see merge-commit changes, do that too.